# Expanding local repo .git contents

Tags: git

If I copy `<local repo path>\.git` from `wksA` to `wksB`, as a shortcut for having to publish to a remote repo and clone from there, is there a git command for expanding the folder and file contents of that copied `<local repo path>\.git` on the target system?

Comment: This is not a good idea. There are several things inside the repository that are local to that instance (reflogs etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than copying the .git directory (which might have hard-coded paths in it), you should just make a local clone from your original directory.

```
git clone /path/to/wksA wksB
```

This doesn't need you to go through a remote, creates a clean (properly set up) copy of the repository, and has the added advantage, BTW, that you can use wksA as a remote (think 'local backup')

Comment: on wksB i first tried "git clone \\wksa\src\repos\localOnlyRepo d:\src\repos\localOnlyRepo" and that produced a "fatal: '\\wksA\src\repos\localOnlyRepo' does not appear to be a git repository".   I then retried replacing source repo path backslashes with forward slashes, i.e. "git clone //wksa/src/repos/localOnlyRepo d:\src\repos\localOnlyRepo" and that worked.  Appears the expectation is you use unix style forward slashes in cifs/smb path arguments on windows wks setups.

Comment: The first part (the path/to/repo) is a URI, hence the forward slash

Answer (score 2):

Simply pick a branch and checkout it:

```
git checkout master
```

You can specify the current folder as well:

```
git checkout master -- .
```

Comment: i tried "git checkout master" which didn't produce any errors but I couldn't find any files afterwards in root of repo folder containing just hidden .git folder contents . . . so not sure what it did or if it pulled out files where it put them.  I then tried "git checkout master -- ." and that expanded the .git folder contents in to the current folder.

Comment: @ob1cot yes, if you mention the path, it reset the working tree, forcing all files to be copied.